# What's wrong with the batch file?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, conditional-statements

A very annoying error in my batch program causes it to stop. I'm sure it's somewhere in the `IF` statement but I'm a beginner and I can't find anything on the web so I came here

```
:englog
CLS
set/p "login=login: "
set/p "password=password: "
if %login%.txt exist AND if %password% == %login%.txt goto logedEng
if %login%.txt not exist OR if not %password% == %login%.txt goto englog & start didntloggedin.vbs
```

Comment: `:englog` <-> `goto logedEng` and `goto englog` - maybe?

Comment: It's "IF EXIST %login%.txt"  There is no "AND" command in Batch. Then you are saying "IF <variable> == File goto LogedEng.

Comment: ... that also, = multiple problems.

Comment: @Larryc that doesn't work. You can't put `&&` in the if command body because it expects another command

Comment: There is no AND command, there is no OR command.  IF and EXIST go together, same with IF NOT EXIST.  The labels in your goto commands muist be preceded with a colon as in GOTO :LABEL.

Comment: Then drop && and indent your code on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

The if syntax is wrong. Run `if /?` to know how to use it:

```
Performs conditional processing in batch programs.

IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
```

As you can see, it doesn't support `AND` and NOT must be put before the comparison. And why do you use `goto englog & start didntloggedin.vbs`. Once you go to another line then how can you run the command on the old line?

Another issue is that errors will happen if the variable is blank (like when the user enters nothing). You need to wrap the string inside quotes so that it works every time. For an AND condition use multiple IFs like this

```
if exist "%login%.txt" if "%password%" == "%login%.txt" goto logedEng
```